# strongSwan: Accessing LAN of a Windows client (reversed remote access)

Tags: remote-access, strongswan, tunneling, ikev2

I am currently having an Ubuntu Server strongSwan setup (IKEv2, EAP-MSCHAPv2) that will allow any authorized remote Windows client to access server's LAN (192.168.7.0/24). It works perfectly, but I wonder if there is a way to invert that? What I mean is that I would want to access CLIENT's LAN, e. g. 192.168.8.0/24. There is NO server on the other side. Is this even possible? Can I use the same connection/tunnel for that? The problem is that client's network is behind ISP's NAT and has its private IP, so I am unable (or don't know how) to deploy the server on the other side.